# How to create an adminhtml grid with custom category attribute?

Tags: adminhtml, eav, magento2.2.2

I am starting my adventure with Magento 2.2.2, so my question may be considered stupid by most of you.

I'm trying to write a module, which adds custom category attribute and then displays it on custom adminhtml view.

I already managed to add such custom category attribute, but I am having problems with displaying a grid with all categories and my custom attributes on custom admin webpage.

Could anyone point me in a direction I should take to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tutorials out there one of them is this.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

Another one

https://magecomp.com/blog/create-admin-grid-magento-2/

And another one

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-a-grid-using-ui-component/

Comment: Thank you for the response, but these tutorials only show how to create a grid. My main problem is how to populate it with EAV data for categories. Unless my approach is wrong and I should use CRUD tables instead? They seem much easier to use...

Comment: @Gumili Your overthinking it. Just feed the category collection to the grid and that's it. You don't have to think about it in terms of crud tables or eav data. Category management is already implemented.